# Not checking for the existing file? PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a user account system using text documents. But the issue i'm having with my code is that it just overwrites the document rather than testing if it exists first then if it doesn't create the document. Any ideas why this is?

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['NewUsername'])){
        if (isset($_GET['NewPassword'])){           
            $NewPassword = $_GET['NewPassword'];
            $NewUsername = $_GET['NewUsername'];
            if (file_exists("USERS/".$NewUsername)) {
                echo 'Error: User Already Exists!';
            }
            else{
                $myFile=fopen("USERS/".$NewUsername.".txt","w") or exit("Can’t open file!");
                fwrite($myFile, $NewPassword);
                fclose($myFile);
                echo 'Account Created!';
            }
        }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Try this: `if (file_exists("USERS/".$NewUsername.".txt")) {`

Comment: 1. You should never ever store plain-text passwords, always salt and hash them, 2. You should not store this in the web-root (can anybody open them?), 3. You should not use GET but POST for this (the values will appear in the browser's history...), 4. See 1.

Comment: Also attention to creating files with whatever characters you get from somebody on the internet. You might end up with files having very nasty names that behave badly if used with some command line tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are writing to a file with a `.txt` extension - but you are using `file_exists` to test for a file without the extension....

So, change

```
if (file_exists("USERS/".$NewUsername)) {
```

to:

```
if (file_exists("USERS/".$NewUsername ."txt")) {
```

Comment: Read back through it and notices this, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct file name to check if file already exists. Try changing the code with the one below.

```
if (file_exists("USERS/".$NewUsername.".txt")) {
```